# How to train AI to recognize a Snapchat's bitmoji's gender

Tags: python, training, image-recognition, ai

I would like to enable my Python script to get a vague idea of a bitmoji's gender.

I found these two git repositories that are able to differentiate between them.

How would I use them to have my script recognize which gender a bitmoji has from an image "testbitmoji.png" for example?

[Larry-zx's Githubproject](https://github.com/Larry-zx/bitmoji-faces-gender-recognition)

[Reloof's Githubproject](https://github.com/Reloof/Bitmoji_Faces_Gender_Recognition_with_resnet-50)

Comment: Yes, your idea is on the right path, now you "just" have to do this.

Comment: @user2974951Thanks for your comment. I'd appreciate any leads or useful advice on how and where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into finding datasets for bitmojis. One is available on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/romaingraux/bitmojis), but you will have to manually label them yourself.

Once you have the data ready and set, you can proceed with building your classifier.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found this gitrepositorys which seem to have achived what I am looking for. I do not understand much thohttps://github.com/Larry-zx/bitmoji-faces-gender-recognition

Comment: Now that you have that, you can look into CNNs maybe. You have the images, the labels, and plenty of features. You are one big step ahead having found such a dataset.